# Eigen slerp resulting in a Read Access Violation (C++/OpenGL)

Tags: c++, vector, eigen, quaternions

I'm calling `slerp()` from the [Eigen libary](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) as follows:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf Rtime = (Eigen::Quaternionf::Identity().slerp(timer, quarts[i])).toRotationMatrix();
```

where `timer` is a float and quarts is declared as

```
std::vector<Eigen::Quaternionf> quarts;
```

This call to slerp only causes a **Read Access Violation** sometimes (about 50% of the time) , which confuses me.

Looking at the stack frame, [image: Stack Frame]
I can see that the code reaches `Eigen::internal::pload` until it breaks.

Generally I'd think that my indices are incorrect but it crashes even when 
`i = 0` and `quarts.size() = 1`. I declare the only quaternion in the vector:

```
Eigen::Matrix3f rotMatrix;
    rotMatrix = U * V;
    Eigen::Quaternionf temp;
    temp = rotMatrix;
    quarts.push_back(temp);
```

where `U` and `V` come from a computation of Singular Value Decomposition, so maybe there's something wrong with the way I declare the quaternion? Or storing it in a vector in some way affects it? I'm not sure.

Comment: _Or storing it in a vector in some way affects it?_ This is what I considered also. AFAIK, Eigen may use [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) when compiled for Intel CPUs which in turn require special alignment of data. [`Eigen::QuaternionBase::slerp()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1QuaternionBase.html#title28) takes a const reference to second end point. Did you try without `std::vector`?

Comment: @Scheff I have a similar program which doesn't use `std::vector` and it works fine. The issue is that I'm expanding the usage and I need multiple quaternions. I tried to store one quaternion within the corresponding Triangle struct but that wasn't working either (it seemed that it would round the floating point values after storing it within the Triangle).

Comment: About `Eigen::Quaternionf::Identity()`: I really _believe_ that the life time of the returned Quaternion should be long enough to complete `toRotationMatrix()`. However, these rules are complicated and I'm not sure whether I fully understood it. If in doubt, I would move this to a local variable: `Eigen::MatrixXf Rtime = [&]() { Eigen::Quaternionf::Identity quatId; return quatId.slerp(timer, quarts[i])).toRotationMatrix(); }();` (The trick with the lambda is really not necessary but it neatly minimizes the life time of `quatId` like it was for the temporary instance in the original version.)

Comment: If you can confirm that storage in `std::vector` causes the trouble (and there are no other "stupid" bugs), when the work-around is simple: just copy the quaternions to temp. variables. It sounds strange but I already read about other issues concerning Eigen, SSE, and alignment problems in the past...

Comment: @Scheff thanks for the help! Instead of storing the quaternions in a `std::vector`, I stored `RotMatrix` instead and that seems to do the trick.

Comment: A [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) consists actually of 4 floating point values, only. So, you even could store the values only and re-build the `Eigen::Quaternionf` when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Quaternionf` requires 16 bytes alignment that is not guaranteed by `std::vector`. More details [there](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html). The solutions are either to use an aligned allocator, e.g.:

```
std::vector<Quaternionf,Eigen::aligned_allocator<Quaternionf>> quats;
```

or to use non-aligned quaternions within the vector:

```
std::vector<Quaternion<float,Eigen::DontAlign>> quats;
```